# jquery nicescroll couldn't make cursor-drag on touch devices

Tags: jquery, touches, nicescroll

Is it possible to scroll by dragging cursor (handle - in other words) on touch devices?
Now it is scrolled only when I touching list, and cursor seems to be disabled.

Comment: which device you use?